# Writing Python Variable to Multiple Text Files

Tags: python, file, variables

The output of the following code is shown in the attached image:

```
print(reg_num)
print(final_df)
```

[image: Image of Ouput]
 ^^^Outputs of `print(reg_num)`and`print(final_df)` as visible on terminal^^^

In the output image, 6 lines of outputs are visible. Pairs of 3 each. I want to save each pair into separate text files.

Expected output:

output1.txt

```
16SCSE102014
2
```

output2.txt

```
16SCSE101350
0
```

output3.txt

```
16SCSE101002
0
```

My attempt:

```
z = [reg_num, final_df]
print(z)
ctr = 0
for i in z:
  ctr += 1
  with open('d:\\output'+str(ctr)+'.txt', 'w') as f:
     for j in range(len(z)):
     f.write((str(z[j]) + "\n"))
```

but I couldn't bring the required data into the text files.

What is the solution?

Comment: change the line `for j in range(len(z)):` to `for j in i:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the thing.
The output files will appear in the same directory you run the python script from.

```py
results = [['2001ABCD2001', '40'],
           ['4002ABCD4002', '30'],
           ['2005WXYZ2005', '20']]

ctr = 0
for res in results:
    ctr += 1
    with open("output{}.txt".format(ctr), 'w') as f:
        f.write("\n".join(res))
        f.write("\n")    # final newline
```

Comment: Its getting the target right, but the text file is being printed character by character in one char per row.

Comment: That's weird, it doesn't for me and it actually shouldn't for you either. Did you run this exact snippet?

Comment: f.write("\n".join(res)) is returning the error - can only join iterables. So I replaced that with str(results) which is a list and hence an iterable. That results in one character per row output to the respective text files. Also it wrote only two files with same data in each  instead of three files with respective data.

Comment: **res** is an iterable in my snippet since it is a list of strings. So I'm asking again, did you run this exact same snippet as a standalone script or did you merge it into your own code? Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: I merged your exact snippet. Using Python 3. Can you just run your code on res = ["16SCSCE2001", "2"] and put it into a text? I'll take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

```
z = [['2001ABCD2001', '40'],
     ['4002ABCD4002', '30'],
     ['2005WXYZ2005', '20']]

for index, row in enumerate(z, 1):
    dest = "d:\\output{}.txt".format(index)
    with open(dest, 'w') as f:
        f.writelines("{}\n".format(cell) for cell in row)
```

Comment: Your answer would be way better if you included some explanation in it.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you could just write the elements of each sub-list:

```
z = [['2001ABCD2001', '40'],
     ['4002ABCD4002', '30'],
     ['2005WXYZ2005', '20']]

ctr = 0
for i in z:
    ctr += 1
    with open('output'+str(ctr)+'.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write((i[0] + "\n" + i[1]))
```

Here the text files are written in the same directory where the python script is run from.

Comment: My question has changed. I think I misunderstood the list in list concept. Please hae a look again.

Answer (score -1):

```
a = ['2001ABCD2001', '40']
b = ['4002ABCD4002', '30']

c = "2005WXYZ2005"        
d = "20"

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(d) # 4 final outputs of the main program to be saved to diff files.

z = [a] # my attempt on just 'a'
ctr = 0
for i in z:
    ctr += 1
    with open('output'+str(ctr)+'.txt', 'w') as f: #ctr to increment name of file
        for j in range(len(a)): 
            f.write((str(a[j])+"\n"))
```

Comment: Hi easycodeyeasy, following your snippet I realized a mistake. So I re-edited my question and included your snippet in it. Could you help me out on this? My question is a lot more closer to what I want to get now.

Comment: This needs to create 3 txt files.